# How to stop IsPostBack from a textbox carriage return?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, textbox, autopostback

I want to stop the IsPostBack fired from the enter key pressed at a TextBox. The textBox can not be multiline.

I'm trying this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="kemetTextBox" runat="server" Width="215px">      
                </asp:TextBox>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#kemetTextBox").keyup(function (e) {
                            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                                Search();
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

But it stills reloading the page.

Data: Visual Studio 2010, Asp.net, C# as codebehind.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `AutoPostBack="False"` like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="kemetTextBox" runat="server" Width="215px" AutoPostBack="False">
```

[TextBox.AutoPostBack Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx)

> Use the AutoPostBack property to specify whether an automatic postback
>   to the server will occur when the TextBox control loses focus.
>   Pressing the ENTER or the TAB key while in the TextBox control is the
>   most common way to change focus.

---

Adding to this you can do this too:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="kemetTextBox" runat="server" Width="215px" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);">
```

Source: [Disable Enter key in TextBox to avoid postback in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/disable-enter-key-in-textbox-to-avoid-postback-in-asp.net.aspx)

Comment: That property was already false at Visual Studio interface. But thanks for the help. Btw, may be I didn't explain myself. I just want to avoid the "enter" function in that TextBox.

Comment: Edited the answer to get you covered. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of KeyUp, use keyDown

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#kemetTextBox").keydown(function (e) {
                            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                                Search();
                                e.preventDefault();
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```